# Scheduled Python script in task scheduler not working

Tags: python, gspread

I have a python script that I am trying to schedule to run in the task scheduler in my VM but it doesn't seem to be running, it returns (0x2) for last run result. I am able to run the script manually and it works. I even created a batch file to execute the script which works and tried scheduling that in Task Scheduler but it also gave the same error. My only guess is that it's not working because it uses the Google Sheets API and reads the credentials from a JSON file in the project folder but I'm still unsure as to why it wouldn't run when scheduled. If you have any ideas I would greatly appreciate it. In the task scheduler, I am using the path `Z:\Python\PythonGSAPI\executePy.bat` to execute the batch file. The content of the batch file is

```
@echo off
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "Z:\Python\PythonGSAPI\TF_Invoice.py"
pause
```

Comment: Can you redirect the output to a file?

Comment: The first place I'd look is the environment variables that the program inherits when it starts (`os.environ`). There might be some differences in how it's launched in the scheduler and on your own command line.

Comment: In your Python script, is the path to the JSON file absolute? Otherwise, it's possible that the scheduled task is starting from a different directory, and doesn't know where that file is.

Answer (score 0):

This occur due the PATH Enviroment variable, for exemple, if you use Anaconda Python it's needed to choose the first option during the installation or even configure this after.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F0Ca.png)